# I want to store one day before's date

Tags: php, mysql

How to store the one day before's date of selected date.

I want to store the date of one day before from selected date from the datepicker,

Date formate: DD/MM/YY

```
 insert into appointment_notification set date='"..$_POST['date']"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : date('Y-m-d');
$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into appointment_notification (date)
values ('"..$_POST['date']"' - interval 1 day)
```

But you really need to escape your user input to prevent SQL syntax errors and SQL injections. Have a look at PDO or mysqli.

Comment: and when @juergen tells really, he means **REALLY**

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your date to a valid format first and sub a day:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/y", $_POST['date']);
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$valid_date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Then you can use:

```
insert into appointment_notification (date)
values ('"'.$valid_date.'"')
```

Don't forget to check if your field effectively contains a valid date before applying this code.